Manually Upload Releases
I use TFS version 16. I have my code saved in a Git repo. The file that I deploy is a zip file that is made on my PC. Whenever I am ready to release my code, I want to manually upload the Zip file to a release location in Azure with its version number. It seems silly to place released zip files into a folder held by the Git repo, but that can be done. Is there a cleaner way of manually placing files onto the project? What would be ideal is something like what Dropbox or Google Drive have, where files can be seamlessly uploaded be dropping them into a folder.
I tried looking into the Release settings, but the only options required pipelines and no options to get artifacts from an upload.

I have my code saved in a Git repo, what's the Git repo detail here? Is it cloud(eg: github) or On-prem TFS git? Are you looking for manually uploading release zip file to above git repo?

On-prem TFS and yes. But I don't want the zip files to live in the commit history of the repo.

You could use universal packages to store the zip file. However, the more correct answer is to take whatever you're manually doing to create those zip files, automate it, and turn it into a pipeline. Then your pipeline will have associated output artifacts that you can use.

For on-premises TFS, Git repositories are stored within the SQL Server database that TFS uses, they are stored together with all the other data, but not stored as individual files or folders.
If you need a UI tool to seamlessly upload or drop files from the repo, you can use VS Code, SourceTree..etc.
But, Git inherently tracks changes through commits, so completely avoiding a commit history for the current upload isn’t possible. It will have the commit history if you upload zip files.

Backticks (``) are for code blocks, not emphasis.
